# Why won't this LINQ TO SQL query come back in the right order?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
(from assetVisit in AssetVisits
                        join assetBundle in AssetBundles on assetVisit.AssetID equals assetBundle.AssetID
                        join groupBundle in GroupBundles on assetBundle.BundleID equals groupBundle.BundleID
                        join userGroup in UserGroups on groupBundle.GroupID equals userGroup.GroupID
                        where assetVisit.CompanyID == 32 &&
                              userGroup.UserID == 75
                        orderby assetVisit.AccessCounter descending
                        select assetVisit).Distinct()
```

notice the 'order by' however when the data comes back it is ordered by the PK of the assetVisit table, what gives?

SQL PER LINQPAD:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int SET @p0 = 32
DECLARE @p1 Int SET @p1 = 75
-- EndRegion
SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[AssetVisitID], [t0].[CompanyID], [t0].[AssetID], [t0].[AccessCounter], [t0].[CreateBy], [t0].[CreateDate], [t0].[ModifyBy], [t0].[ModifyDate]
FROM [AssetVisits] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [AssetBundles] AS [t1] ON [t0].[AssetID] = ([t1].[AssetID])
INNER JOIN [GroupBundles] AS [t2] ON ([t1].[BundleID]) = [t2].[BundleID]
INNER JOIN [UserGroups] AS [t3] ON [t2].[GroupID] = [t3].[GroupID]
WHERE ([t0].[CompanyID] = @p0) AND ([t3].[UserID] = @p1)
```

Comment: What type is AccessCounter? What SQL does this query generate?

Comment: ahh good call it doesn't look like there is any ordering in the SQL version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "order by" should be *after* the distinct.

```
    (from assetVisit in AssetVisits
     join assetBundle in AssetBundles on assetVisit.AssetID equals assetBundle.AssetID
     join groupBundle in GroupBundles on assetBundle.BundleID equals groupBundle.BundleID
     join userGroup in UserGroups on groupBundle.GroupID equals userGroup.GroupID
     where assetVisit.CompanyID == 32 &&
               userGroup.UserID == 75
     select assetVisit).Distinct().OrderByDescending(assetVisit => assetVisit.AccessCounter);
```

Or if you wish to keep using the query syntax, you could write it like this instead:

```
    var innerQuery =
        (from assetVisit in AssetVisits
         join assetBundle in AssetBundles on assetVisit.AssetID equals assetBundle.AssetID
         join groupBundle in GroupBundles on assetBundle.BundleID equals groupBundle.BundleID
         join userGroup in UserGroups on groupBundle.GroupID equals userGroup.GroupID
         where assetVisit.CompanyID == 32 &&
                   userGroup.UserID == 75
         select assetVisit).Distinct();

    var query = from assetVisit in innerQuery
            orderby assetVisit.AccessCounter descending
            select assetVisit;
```

Comment: ahh.. but this: Distinct().OrderBy(assetVisit.AccessCounter descending) throws an error, how is it suppose to really look?

Comment: what is 'asset' where does it come from?

Comment: It's the parameter for the OrderBy function. It probably should be called assetVisit, I will change it.

Comment: Ryan: I've updated my answer with another version that uses only syntax that you are already familiar with. I hope you can understand the second version in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this before.  The distinct operator "undoes" any ordering that you have specified earlier in your LINQ statment.

Here's a good explaination:
http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/07/20/use-of-distinct-and-orderby-in-linq.aspx